# Multithread Data Transfer between Oracle & SQL Server - Network Performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, oracle, ssis

We want to transfer a huge amount of data between Oracle 11g R2 & SQL Server 2014 in a little amount of time... we are talking about 20+ Tb, thousands of tables, and billions of records (it's a 5 year Datawarehouse)

SSIS it's not an option, because the amount of tables & partitions we need to transfer is huge, about 40k tables & partitions.. we have some Marketing Apps, Campaign Managers, Mining Models, and others, running in different schemas... some of them create about 150 new tables daily, and the "drop table rate" it's about 100 daily... some of this tables have indexes, some not... this schemas are the reason why we can't simply use SSIS, cause we need to transfer them too...
*Edit to include more info about why SSIS doesn't look a viable option*

So we developed an app in C# 2013 with .Net 4.5.1, and it's multithreaded... each thread read a table / partition in oracle, creates the same table / partition schema in sql server, and proceed to select the data in oracle, and bulk inserted in sql server, and finally, create every pending constraint and index...

One of the main problems we are facing is the transfer speed... Comparing the SSIS performance transferring 1 fact table with 30 partitions (monthly fact, daily partition, about 30 million rows per partition, 60+ columns) against our C# app, we found the app never uses full network speed while the SSIS uses 100% (we use the Attunity SSIS Connectors for Oracle... and probably one of the speed transfer advantages is here, i dunno), and we want to improve this if we can...

This is the code block in charge of the write

```
//private static async Task saveDataBlock(IDataReader reader, string destinationTable, int batchSize)
private static void saveDataBlock(IDataReader reader, string destinationTable, int batchSize)
{
    //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy bc = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(getConnString(destinationCS));
    //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy bc = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(getConnString(destinationCS), System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity & System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls & System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock);
    using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(getConnString(destinationCS)))
    {
        bc.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
        bc.DestinationTableName = destinationTable;
        bc.BatchSize = batchSize; //2500,5000,10000.. best so far, 5000
        //bc.BatchSize = 0;
        bc.NotifyAfter = batchSize;
        bc.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(s_SqlRowsCopied);
        //bc.EnableStreaming = true;            

        bc.ColumnMappings.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetName(i));
        }

        bc.WriteToServer(reader);
        //await bc.WriteToServerAsync(reader);
        //bc.Close();
    }

    //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy bc = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(getConnString(destinationCS), SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction);            

}
```

Anyone have any suggestions about any option we can test of configure (the commented sections of the code are from previous tested options), in SQL Server or the SQLBulkCopy object in the C# app?

PS: some info about our environment...
Oracle Server Client Uplink 2 Gbps, SQL Server Downlink 1 Gbps, Oracle is a 32 core system, our test SQL Server is a 16 core Win Server 2012 R2 system... SSIS Net transfer speed is 1 Gbps full, C# App Net transfer speed is about 70 mbps, with 16 threads...

*Edit for bring more info about the transfer speeds*

More info about our app testings:

2 threads = 15-25 Mbps

4 threads = 30-40 Mbps

8 threads = 60-65 Mbps

16 threads = 65-70 Mbps

Everything above 16 (1 app thread per system core) bring down the performance to 30-50 Mbps..

Our SAN is very capable of speeds above 500 MB/s, at a High I/O count

Our best batch size times we got it with values between 2500-5000 rows per batch (about 15 million rows in 5 minutes, with 8-16 threads)

Right now our app transfer data from one table/partition in oracle to other in SQL Server... we have some non partitioned tables with 100+ million rows... for this tables we tested multiple threads reading the same table... we succeeded at the read process, but failed at the bulk insert of data

Every thread reads the same table doing a MOD operation over a numeric column...

```
select * from schema.table where MOD(NUMERIC_COLUMN, N) = 0 to N-1
```

N it's the number of threads we are running... We tried to recreate some SSIS behaviors to maximize thread use & data read / write in Oracle/SQL.. In SSIS we can set every thread with the LOCK TABLE option at destination, and it worked flawless.. but while doing it in our app, every thread lock the table during the insert, and finally our parallelized design runs serialized :( (This isn't the main reason of the question, but if someone have suggestions about this, it will be appreciated)

Comment: When you run SSIS and the c# app, do you see any difference in the Wait types/times for the writes to SQL?

Comment: Out of perverse curiosity, could you help me understand `SSIS it's not an option, because the amount of tables & partitions we need to transfer is huge` It seems that it handles the speed just fine compared to your homegrown system

Comment: so how many threads are you creating?  Having many many threads run simultaneously is going to be a big perf hit.  Show more code.

Comment: @BradD actually i'm not controlling the wait types / times

Comment: @billinkc the problem is we have about 40K tables in our different oracle schemas... because some apps from the marketing area running over our dwh (in house developed), our users can create segments of data, their segments creates final tables, and that's about 150 new tables... some of them with indexes... if we create a DTS task we need to create previously all the objects... create the connections, match the columns, and optimize every stream with the attunity drivers... it's not an easy work for the team... whe need to translate our oracle package and views to sql server procedures too

Comment: @TMcKeown we create the threads based on a parameter.. we tested 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 threads... the logic is simple.. we first create the objects selected to transfer, tables and partitions are taken from a list.. once this ends, we assing each object (a table o table partition) to a thread and begin the transfer... when the thread finalizes with 1 object, takes one more from the list and starts again... once all the objects of the list finish their transfers, the app creates all the indexes needed... i'm at home right now, so i don't have access to the code to post it, but really the app is simple

Comment: First off, I hope you know it's SSIS, not DTS. Second, since the days of DTS it's been possible to create a package programmatically. You should be able to automatically create the package you need, and let SSIS do all the work. That's what it's made for.

Comment: Also, how often will you be running this 20TB of data?

Comment: @JohnSaunders ... Well the data will be moved in different stages ... But in the end, daily we will need to move about 1 tb of data from the Oracle servers to the SQL Servers.. I will try what you say about the SSIS/DTS.. We actually have a lot of dts packages to process our data in Oracle.. My test was really a dts data transfer task with multiple oracle atunnity connections to transfer data from the different partitions to our sql test environment.. I will try to make the dts programmatically and test it..

Comment: Do you mean DTS or SSIS? Which version of SQL Server are you using for the packages? And remember that the server running SSIS does not need to be the same server running the database engine.

Comment: I agree with John.  I don't think I've ever seen a clearer example of when programmatic SSIS packages are the correct answer.  If I had more experience with them, I'd mock up an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't far from the theoretical maximum throughput on a 1Gbps link.  1Gbps max throughput is 125 MB/s WITHOUT any overhead.  You’re really looking at 90 MB/s actual and if you are going through a layer 3 switch, router, or firewall that is having to process the packets the throughput is going to drop.  Your best bet is to get the servers on the same network segment and get a higher speed link between them.  I suspect the reason your throughput is dropping when the thread count is higher is because the threads are fighting over access to the NIC (or the NIC is introducing a delay per packet due to the large packet size) and the threads are having the pause execution (sleep) and try again.

I think your problem is throughput.  Try a higher speed connection by bonding two 1Gbps links.  Or if the servers are close to each other, connect them directly (no switch) using a crossover cable to see if the transfer speeds increase.  If they do, you know you have a throughput issue.  If they don't, you've at least eliminated a possibility.